# How to prune subtree in python

Tags: python, tree, reduce

I am (still) dealing with a tree structure in a Python program.
Each node in a tree has a dictionary "children", whose keys hold arc information, and values
are the child nodes. (And each node has a (parent, parent_arc) pair, where parent is its parent node and parent_arc is the arc by which the parent node link this node.)

Now I want to prune a subtree, whose root is a child of a node N. Say the child is N.children[a].

del N.children[a] simply won't release the memory occupied by the subtree. Do I have to implement a method to delete every node in the subtree? How can I do this ? Do I need to re-define the node class for efficient subtree pruning?

Thank you!

Comment: If N.children[a] owns its children, then deleting N.children[a] will remove all references to those children. I don't see the problem.

Comment: but the (parent,parent_arc) pair of N.children[a].children[x] holds reference to N.children[a] . I guess that prevents the nodes being deleted.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `parent_arc` terminology, but if you want objects to be eligible for garbage collection, then you simply must release all references to them. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @David It won't actually release all references, because (cPython at least) uses reference counting, and this structure has cycles (ie the children have children, which refer back to their parents).

Comment: Though according to (http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.0.html) "Python 2.0 fixes this problem by periodically executing a cycle detection algorithm which looks for inaccessible cycles and deletes the objects involved." So it's possible that when you say it "simply won't release the memory", it really just never felt like running cycle detection, so it's not an actual problem.

Comment: Also more info on when cycles are detected here: http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Python_Garbage_Collection#Automatic_Garbage_Collection_of_Cycles . It looks like you should be good with what you have.

Comment: @Owen, Thanks for your input. I end up with gc.collect(), which detects cycle and release memory. I will probably try weakref at a later stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When A -> B and B -> A you have reference cycles.  A good way to get around that is to have the children use weak references to point back to the parent.  Something like this:

```
import weakref
class Node():
    parent = None
    child = None
    @property
    def parent(self):
        parent = self._parent()
        if parent is not None:
            return parent
        raise ValueError("parent has been deleted")
    @parent.setter     # python 2.6+
    def parent(self, parent):
        self._parent = weakref.ref(parent)
```

Now, the node does not have a direct link to its parent, and when you delete the child it really will go away*.  (You may need to use the same method for the parent_arc.)

*Note that even though Python will release the objects more quickly if no reference cycles exist, it may not give that memory back to the OS.